# npm install fails with node-gyp errors for libxmljs

Tags: npm, libxml-js

I'm trying to run a node project that uses `libxmljs`, but it fails on installing it, with

```
npm "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"
```

I've tried different versions of `npm`, but none of helped, all have the same problem it appears.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this project, I managed to fix it by simply using a newer version of libxml in my package.json

I bumped it up to `v0.18` from `v0.11`

```
"dependencies":{
    "libxmljs": "^0.18.0"
}
```

then running `npm install` again. I don't know if it matters or not, but I also removed my `~/.node-gyp` folder as well. Note that this solution was suggested by [a comment on a similar github issue](https://github.com/AirAsiaExpedia/node-simple-xml/issues/5#issuecomment-103977637)